# trigger event on acf tab click - how to

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, advanced-custom-fields

I would like it so that when a user clicks on a particular TAB on an ACF form, this triggers a javascript event.

Something like:

```
$('#acf-field_57f8b36e99fcb').on('click', function() {
    alert ("tab clicked");
});
```

But this doesn't work. (Nor does .focusin, .focusout etc).

Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?

Comment: What kind of HTML element does that selects?

Comment: Have you included proper jQuery library? You are using a delegate so you should use proper `.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

When you add any field dynamically you need to bind jquery/Javascript function again with it.